# dplyr 'object not found' median only

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

This problem has me stumped.

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

# approximation of data frame
x <- data.frame(doy = sample(c(seq(200, 300)), 20, replace = T),
                year = sample(c("2000", "2005"), 20, replace = T), 
                phase = sample(c("pre", "post"), 20, replace = T))
```

and a simple 'summarize' function that takes in the column name as a variable, and works nicely:

```
 getStats <- function(df, col) {
      col <- as.name(col)
      df %>% 
        group_by(year, phase) %>% 
        summarize(n = sum(!is.na(col)), 
                  mean = mean(col, na.rm = T),
                  sd = sd(col, na.rm = T),
                  se = sd/sqrt(n))
 }

> getStats(x, "doy")
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: year [?]

    year  phase     n    mean       sd       se
  <fctr> <fctr> <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1   2000   post     8 248.625 30.42526 10.75695
2   2000    pre     2 290.000 14.14214 10.00000
3   2005   post     5 231.400 32.86031 14.69558
4   2005    pre     5 274.200 29.79429 13.32441
```

However, if I modify the function to get the median, it returns an error:

```
 getStats <- function(df, col) {
      col <- as.name(col)
      df %>% 
        group_by(year, phase) %>% 
        summarize(n = sum(!is.na(col)), 
                  mean = mean(col, na.rm = T),
                  med = median(col, na.rm = T), # new line 
                  sd = sd(col, na.rm = T),
                  se = sd/sqrt(n))
    }

> getStats(x, "doy")

Error in median (doy, na.rm = TRUE): object "doy" not found
```

I've tried a host of name and position changes, but all yield the same result: 'median' doesn't accept the column name as a passed variable. I assume I'm missing something so basic I'll do a face palm when someone points it out to me, but in the interim I feel like I'm losing my sanity.  I appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proximal problem may be that `median` doesn't have a `...` argument, while `mean` does (I'm not sure why `sd` is working ... maybe an interaction between methods and `...`?)

In any case, IMO the right way to handle this sort of problem is to use *standard* evaluation (i.e., *not* non-standard evaluation, i.e. use `summarise_` rather than `summarise`, as illustrated in `vignette("nse",package="dplyr")`):

Illustrating how this works in the global environment rather than inside a function, but I think that shouldn't matter ...

```
col <- "doy"
funs <- c("n","mean","stats::median","sd","se")
## put together function calls
dots <- c(sprintf("sum(!is.na(%s))",col),
      sprintf("%s(%s,na.rm=TRUE)",funs[2:4],col),
      "sd/sqrt(n)")
names(dots) <- gsub("^.*::","",funs)  ## ugh
dots 
##                              n                            mean 
##              "sum(!is.na(doy))"          "mean(doy,na.rm=TRUE)" 
##                        median                              sd 
## "stats::median(doy,na.rm=TRUE)"            "sd(doy,na.rm=TRUE)" 
##                              se 
##                    "sd/sqrt(n)" 

x %>% 
    group_by(year, phase) %>% 
    summarise_(.dots=dots)
```

The only annoying thing here is that for some reason `dplyr` can't find `median` unless I call it as `stats::median`, which means we have to work a little harder to get nice column names.  The standard-evaluation method is a little uglier, but that's the price you pay for this kind of flexibility.

Embedding this in a function, I would probably break off `getStats` in a different place, i.e.

```
 getStats <- function(data,col) {
   ## if you want to pass a string argument instead, remove
   ## the next line
   col <- deparse(substitute(col))
   funs <- c("n","mean","stats::median","sd","se")
   dots <- c(sprintf("sum(!is.na(%s))",col),
      sprintf("%s(%s,na.rm=TRUE)",funs[2:4],col),
      "sd/sqrt(n)")
   names(dots) <- gsub("^.*::","",funs)  ## ugh
   summarise_(data,.dots=dots)
}

x %>% group_by(year,phase) %>% getStats(doy)
```

This gives you more flexibility to do different groupings ...

Comment: I'm irrationally cheered by the thought that I would never have come up with this solution on my own.  Thank you for the lightning-fast, thorough, and helpful answer.  For those dealing with the same issue, note that removing the `deparse` line allows the function above to handle a string variable; i.e., `getStats(data, colName)`, where `colName <- "doy"`